# Add number of symbols defined in attribute table or how to set up cluster points with defined number of records in attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, clustering, aggregate-points

I use QGIS 3.22.2 and I have points datasets of records from ecology surveys with few different species and with separate column with number of records in given location (point) - most of points have just one record in that column but some of them have more of records.

How can I make instead of one defined symbol - given number of same symbols next to each other with very small offsets (some kind of points displacement map with defined number of points) or at least cluster points map with given number of records in that point.